# Позиция курсора из под сервиса

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-service

Как определить позицию курсора из программы запущенной как Windows Service. `BOOL GetCursorPos(LPPOINT lpPoint)` не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, все сервисы в windows создаются в специальном окружении, которое не имеет доступа к рабочему столу пользователя.  Поэтому, либо учится работать с драйвером мыши напрямую (но тут такое количество подводных камней...), или просто сделать сервис [интерактивным](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx).